# Fitting an equation with an integral, where upper limit is a variable

Tags: python, curve-fitting, integral

I'm trying to fit an equation that has an integral. The upper limit of the integral is a variable, and as such I'm having trouble using quad as it only accepts floats as limits. I've tried to get around this using a for loop but I still keep getting the same error of 'ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()'.

The equation I'm trying to fit is:

[image: Fit Equation]

I know the constants M and c, and have data for m(z) and z. I'm trying to fit ΩM and ΩΛ.
This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

z=[0.03, 0.05, 0.026, 0.075, 0.026, 0.014, 0.101, 0.02, 0.036, 0.045, 0.043, 0.018, 0.079, 
0.088, 0.063, 0.071, 0.052, 0.05]
m=[16.26, 17.63, 16.08, 18.43, 16.28, 14.47, 19.16, 15.18, 16.66, 17.61, 17.19, 15.61, 
18.27, 19.28, 18.24, 18.33, 17.54, 17.69]
c=299792.458 #speed of light
M=-18.316469239 

def integrand(Z,OM,OV):
    return np.power((((1+Z)**2)*(1+OM*Z)-Z*(2+Z)*OV),-0.5)

def curve(z,OM,OV):
    for i in z:
        I=integrate.quad(integrand,0,i,args=(OM,OV))[0]
    return M+5*np.log10(c*(1+z))*I)                       

popts, pcov=curve_fit(curve,z,m)
```

Thanks in advance and hope that includes everything!

Comment: That image is an eye chart.  Perhaps provide one that's a little larger, with more resolution?

Comment: What exactly is the difference to your other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53400945/how-do-i-fit-a-function-that-includes-an-integral-with-a-variable-limit

Comment: in the loop of `curve` you want `i` not `z` in the integrand! That works but does not converge. Probably the starting values of your Omegas have to be chosen well.

Comment: also noticed that `I` should be inside the `log`

Comment: ...and are you sure that `c` in in meter per second...this equation looks unitless to me. Had my cosmology lectures  quite long ago, but something does not add up here.

Comment: ...for the interested http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/304265/fulltext/

Comment: @Mr.T Hi, I've fiddled around with the code a bit more and am a new user so only have just been allowed to embed pictures so thought I could present it all better by rewriting. I'm new, am I not supposed to do that?

Comment: @mikuszefski you're quite right, I missed off a bracket and c is supposed to be km/s! And changing to i works thank you! I've now added in some starting values for the omegas but doesn't seem to change anything so far. Thanks for all the suggestions

Comment: please update the post accordingly.

Comment: ...and apart from the fact that your formula requites `OM = 1 - OV` what a reasonable values for those parameters? Should be something around `0.5`, which does not produce the curvature of your data. Still something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to what was commented you only take the last result of the integration loop into account. The corrected code should be like this:

```
from matplotlib import pylab as plt

import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as integrate
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

z=np.asarray([0.03, 0.05, 0.026, 0.075, 0.026, 0.014, 0.101, 0.02, 0.036, 0.045, 0.043, 0.018, 0.079, 
0.088, 0.063, 0.071, 0.052, 0.05])
m=np.asarray([16.26, 17.63, 16.08, 18.43, 16.28, 14.47, 19.16, 15.18, 16.66, 17.61, 17.19, 15.61, 
18.27, 19.28, 18.24, 18.33, 17.54, 17.69])

# sorting of the data is not necessary but nicer when plotting
idx = np.argsort(z)
z = np.take(z, idx)
m = np.take(m, idx)

c=299792458 #speed of light
M=-18.316469239 

def integrand(Z,OM,OV):
    return np.power((((1+Z)**2)*(1+OM*Z)-Z*(2+Z)*OV),-0.5)

def curve(z,OM,OV):
    I = [integrate.quad(integrand,0,i,args=(OM,OV))[0] for i in z]
    return M+5*np.log10(c*(1+z)*I)

popts, pcov=curve_fit(curve,z,m, p0=(1,1))

plt.plot(z,m,'o')
plt.plot(z,curve(z,*popts))
plt.show()
```

And indeed it gives a nice match:

[image: data with fit]

Comment: Thank you so so much, this sorted it!